# Yii::app()->user->getState not working on after redirect url from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, session, yii, nginx

I am doing this:

```
Yii::app()->user->setState('name','john_peter');
```

I am getting the output:

```
 Yii::app()->user->getState('name');
  #john_peter
```

Actually I am calling action from my ajax and in that action setting some value like this:

```
 Yii::app()->user->setState('name','john_peter');
```

to set data in yii session.

After that I am using `window.location` in java-script(After setting value in session) to redirect url on another action.

But there  **I am  getting  empty attribute value  from this `Yii::app()->user->getState('name');`**

It is working fine on `apache server` but when I set yii code on `nginx`. it is not working.?

What am I doing wrong with `Nginx server`?

Comment: have you tried accessing it with `Yii::app()->user->name;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check PHP-FPM's log files also check write permissions of directory where PHP-FPM stores session files, mostly `/var/lib/php/session` or `/tmp`

Comment: I am getting empty attribute value from this Yii::app()->user->getState('name'); after redirect to another action of that controller from java script.

Answer (score 1):

I have to give `#777` permission to this folder:

```
 /var/lib/php/session
```

permission:

```
chmod -R 0777 /var/lib/php/session
```

For writing session data.